# Checking the difference between ES and SQL database

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I currently have a SQL database of ~250,000 records (with unique ID) and every time a record is added to the database, it's also recorded in ES (with the ID). Each record in the database has a deleted field that is used for soft delete (this isn't recorded in ES). Since a record can be soft deleted, the number of documents in ES will always be equal to or greater than the number of non-soft-deleted records in the database.

I also have written code to delete all the documents in ES and to populate it with records that are not deleted so that # ES documents == # of non-deleted documents.

Let's say that I want to check if all non-deleted records are in ES (they should be but let's say that for some reason after adding a record into the database, it fails to index it in ES and we didn't know), what would be the best way?

Originally I was thinking of doing a search for each one of the non-deleted records in the database but then that's ~250,000 GET requests, is there a better way to compare the difference?

Comment: You don't need to do 250K GET request. Using the [multi get API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-get.html) (with `_source: false`), you could retrieve 250 batches of 1000 docs (or less batches of more docs, your mileage may vary) easily.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

1. add the `deleted` field to ES documents as well, and every time you (soft) delete a doc in SQL also update the `deleted` field in ES.
2. In order to get the number of all non-deleted records you just need to count the docs with `deleted:false` - using one simple query.